# TextMate Python bundle non-blocking

Tags: python, django, textmate, textmatebundles, supervisord

I created a bundle in TextMate for restarting the current Django project's associated Supervisor process. Running the code in the Python interpreter successfully restarts the process without blocking, however when I use it as a TextMate bundle (set to run every time I save .py file) it blocks the GUI for ~3 seconds. Is there any way I can avoid this?

Here's what the code looks like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
import threading

projname = os.environ.get('TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY', '').rpartition('/')[2]


def restart_proj(projname=None):
    """ Restart a supervisor instance.
    Assumes that the name of the supervisor instance is the basename for
    TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY.
    """
    if projname:
        subprocess.Popen('$HOME/.virtualenvs/supervisor/bin/' \
                         'supervisorctl restart {0}'.format(projname),
                         shell=True, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'))

t = threading.Thread(target=restart_proj, args=(projname, ))
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably too late, but you would want to close it early with close_fds=True set in the Popen argument. With it specified, it does not wait for a response.

```
subprocess.Popen('$HOME/.virtualenvs/supervisor/bin/' \
                     'supervisorctl restart {0}'.format(projname),
                     shell=True, close_fds=True, stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'))
```

Comment: I don't use this bundle any more. But your assessment seems reasonable!